# How to fix a windows-1256 xml parsing error in android?

Tags: android, xml-encoding

I have an error when parsing an xml document with sax parser in android. Can someone help me fix this error? 
The error looks like this:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 5, column 9: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

The xml document encoding is windows-1256. Here is a sample from the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1256"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
    <channel>
        <title>منتديات عالم المرأة</title>
        <link>http://forum.mn66.com/</link>
        <description>مكياج,فساتين سهرة,ازياء,ملابس,العناية,بالبشرة,بالشعر,بالجسم,وظائف,تسريحات,fashion</description>
        <language>ar</language>
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 23 Nov 2011 08:38:36 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>vBulletin</generator>
        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <image>
            <url>http://forum.mn66.com/images/Ops_fayez/misc/rss.jpg</url>
            <title>منتديات عالم المرأة</title>
            <link>http://forum.mn66.com/</link>
        </image>
        <item>
            <title>ودها تتعلم تسوق</title>
            <link>http://forum.mn66.com/t312645.html</link>
            <pubDate>Wed, 23 Nov 2011 08:31:20 GMT</pubDate>
            <description><![CDATA[‏&#8203;‏&#8203;قالت لـ زوجھا : [ علمني قيادھ السيارھ &#58974; ] !&#8233;فقال لہـا : انتـي گالملگھ . .  &#8233;والملكھ لا تقود يا حبيبتـي&#8233;فقالت لھ : حسنــاً ..&#8233;لن &#1649;قود .. لن أغسـل .. لن أطبـخ !&#8233;لن أربـي الأطفـال !&#8233;لأننـي ” ملگھ “ والملگھ لا تقوم بہذھ المہام &#8233;اضافھ الى اني احتـاج عشرات الخادمـات&#8233;حتى اتفرغ للاهتمام بـ جمالي ;;)...]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<div><div style="margin:auto;text-align:center;"></div><br /><div style="margin:auto;text-align:center;">ودها تتعلم تسوق<br /><br /></div><!-- google_ad_section_start -->‏&#8203;‏&#8203;قالت لـ زوجھا : [ علمني قيادھ السيارھ &#58974; ] !&#8233;فقال لہـا : انتـي گالملگھ . .  &#8233;والملكھ لا تقود يا حبيبتـي&#8233;فقالت لھ : حسنــاً ..&#8233;لن &#1649;قود .. لن أغسـل .. لن أطبـخ !&#8233;لن أربـي الأطفـال !&#8233;لأننـي ” ملگھ “ والملگھ لا تقوم بہذھ المہام &#8233;اضافھ الى اني احتـاج عشرات الخادمـات&#8233;حتى اتفرغ للاهتمام بـ جمالي ;;) &#8233;فقـال لہـا : أمزح معك فديتك =D:s&#8203;&#8203;&#8233;اضغطي الكلتش وعشقي بواحد وارفعي رجلك شوي شوي . . &#8233;&#8233;&#8233;ههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههههه<!-- google_ad_section_end --></div>



]]></content:encoded>
            <category domain="http://forum.mn66.com/f16/">نكت - jokes - ضحك و الصرقعه</category>
            <dc:creator>*ام ماهر*</dc:creator>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://forum.mn66.com/t312645.html</guid>
        </item>
```

I've been looking the past two days for an answer online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

logcat:

> 11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-29 12:48:32.649:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   com.lascivio.womenworld.RSSSection$EfficientAdapter.getCount(RSSSection.java:161)
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:502) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   com.lascivio.womenworld.RSSSection$GetData.onPostExecute(RSSSection.java:90)
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   com.lascivio.womenworld.RSSSection$GetData.onPostExecute(RSSSection.java:1)
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417) 11-29 12:48:32.649:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-29 12:48:32.649:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 11-29 12:48:32.649:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   11-29 12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 11-29
>   12:48:32.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26821):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is the code where the parsing is happening.

```
private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    try
    {
        // setup the url
        URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

        // create the factory
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        // create a parser
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        // create the reader (scanner)
        XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
        // instantiate our handler
        RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
        // assign our handler
        xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
        // get our data via the url class
        InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());




        // perform the synchronous parse           
        xmlreader.parse(is);


        // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
        return theRssHandler.getFeed();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        // if we have a problem, simply return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please,post your logcat error message and/or xml sample

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that it can be answered?

Comment: here

[link](http://forum.mn66.com/external.php?type\x3drss2\x26forumids\x3d102)

Comment: this has to do with the way you instanciate your xml parser. please post the part of your code where you do this.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the xml on another platform with another tool to see if the xml is well formed? Also, can the windows-1256 encoding properly handle all of the characters in your file?

Comment: The LogCat said that the error (NPE) is happening on EfficientAdapter getCount() part in RSSSection.java. Can you post the contents of RSSSection.java here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "windows-1256");
InputSource is = new InputSource(r);
xmlreader.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:  `is.setEncoding("Cp1256");`
after this line `InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());`

Comment: Does your JVM support this charset? JVMs are only REQUIRED to support the 6 charsets listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: If you're using a Sun JVM, it looks like you need to use "Cp1256" as the encoding (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)